# Hash Table in C++ Through Custom Struct and Linked List Classes

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a spell checking program in C++ by reading in a dictionary from a .txt file. I've got the read in function working perfectly fine, the issue I'm coming across is when I try to navigate and add to my linked list.

When I try to set the pointer of the newest node to add, to the value of the head pointer, I'm getting an error stating No viable conversion from 'Node' to 'Node *'.

What is the best way to perform this conversion.

I've already tried turning my 'Node Head;' inside of my linked list class to a pointer but receive the same error.

To start I created my Node struct (Declared in a header file)

```
struct Node
{

private:
    std::string word;
    Node *nextNode;

public:
    //Default constructor
    Node();
    ~Node();

    //My Setters and getters for the class
    void setWord(std::string _word) { word = _word; }
    std::string getWord() { return word; }
    void setNode(Node *_nextNode) { nextNode = _nextNode; }
    Node getNode() { return *nextNode; }

};
```

Followed by my LinkedList Class (Also declared in a Header file)

```
class LinkedList
{

private:
    Node head;
    int listSize;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    void setListSize(int _listSize) { listSize = _listSize; }
    int getListSize() { return listSize; }
    void setHead(Node _head) { head = _head; }
    Node getHead() { return head; }

    //Function that adds the next node to the head
    void addToHead(LinkedList &myList, Node &myNode);

};
```

Heres my Function

```
void LinkedList::addToHead(LinkedList &myList, Node &myNode)
{

    myNode.setNode(myList.getHead().getNode());
    //Here is where I'm getting my error
    //"No viable conversion from 'Node' to 'Node *'

    myList.setHead(myNode);

}
```

Comment: Is the assignment to make your own list and hash-table? Otherwise the C++ standard specifies [a few good and nice standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), including [a hashed "dictionary" type class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Yup, it's a data structure class and we are suppose to create our own linked list for this assignment. After this assignment I'm allowed to use the standard library however. It would be much more convenient...

Comment: `listSize` should be a reflection of the number of links in the linked list. Granting users the ability to change this with a `setListSize` method can only lead to disaster. This leads to a note on getters and setters. The point of making a member `private` is to restrict access. If you have `public` accessor functions that in no way restrict access, you have members that might as well be `public`. Do not add accessors by default, add them only as required and add tests to make sure the user is not attempting to misuse the accessor.

Comment: For example, if `divisor` will crash the program if it is zero, then `setdivisor` should make sure the user cannot set `divisor` to zero. If it does not make this check, it's only use is to have a place to hang a debugger breakpoint to find out who is setting `divisor` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkedList` class shouldn't own the first `Node`.

The member `head` should be a `Node*` width default value `nullptr` (the list is empty).
`listSize` should also have a default value assigned.

```
LinkedList() head(nullptr), listSize(0) {};
```

**Edit**

Personally I would avoid to force the external code to manage the single nodes.
Keep an implementation independent interface.

```
class LinkedList
{

private:
    Node *head_;
    int size_;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    int size() const { return listSize; }
    // insert after the i-th element
    void insert(std::size index, std::string const& word);
    // return the i-th element
    std::string &at(std::size index);
    std::string const &at(std::size index) const;
    // removes the i-th element
    void remove(size::size index);
};
```

In this way you centralize all list manipulation code into the `LinkedList` class.

You should also consider problems related to copying a `LinkedList` object.

Comment: I've tried this, issue with that is it makes it so both of the swaps I perform in the function have the same issue converting from Node to *Node. I'll play with it again this way but originally it didn't compile.

Comment: I've added some suggestions. In particular try to avoid to expose the Node class to the external code. That is just an implementation detail

Comment: @bordia like it or not, `Node head;` is definitely wrong. Whatever other bugs you have in your implementation, this needs to be fixed.

Comment: Node::getNode() should return a Node* not a copy of the node, then setNode() will compile.